# Can we stop accepting / burninate the [image] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we get rid of the [`image`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) tag?  It's way too broad - any question on the site could be tagged this with no value added.  It has no tag wiki or usage description.  It only has 44 questions, none of which could not fit into another tag (or are off topic) from what I saw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I've removed `image` the tag from all questions a little bit at a time. It seems like most of the questions that had the tag suffered from similar problems:

- They weren't very good questions
- It was hard to suggest a replacement tag
- The tag was often used because the word "image" appeared in either the title or body of the question.

Therefore, I don't think `image` should be used as a tag synonym for [image-quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-quality). I can't think of anything else it should be a synonym for.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem very broad.  The thing to do would be to go to each of the 43 questions and retag them (the first one I found had only one tag: [image]).  Once the tag isn't in use in any questions I believe it will disappear after a period of disuse.

I would suggest not editing 43 questions in one go as it will bump them to the front page.

Not sure how to prevent it from making a reappearance - perhaps make it a tag synonym with something more specific like image-quality?

Comment: You can blacklist tags if they keep reappearing (or so I've heard).  Potentially we wouldn't need to do that though.  I'd say don't make [image] a synonym with [image-quality] though.  They don't really mean the same thing

Comment: Well, @Cullub MikeW can't... but it can generally be done, yes. There's some guidance about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/284336). With under 100, it's probably OK for y'all to take care of it yourself through editing but if you decide that it needs to die a fiery death, follow the guidance there. :)

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  I thought mods were automatically all-powerful :).  Probably omnipresent too...  I'd do some editing of tags, but I don't want to flood the edit queue since I can't just edit questions yet.

Comment: @Cullub yeah, that's difficult... though, there are limits to the number of items you can have in the queue at any given time, so that limitation should keep it from getting too out of hand.